# Ant Build Fails for Pig 0.13.0 for Hadoop 2

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, ant, apache-pig

GOAL
I am downloading Apache Pig 0.13.0 and building the pig-0.13.0-h2.jar file. This file is required to run Pig in Hadoop 2 but does not come with the full download. (Any idea why not?)

ERROR MESSAGE FROM ANT

```
  [ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
   [ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
   [ivy:resolve]        [FAILED     ] org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26!jetty.zip:  (0ms)
   [ivy:resolve]    ==== fs: tried
   [ivy:resolve]      /Users/hduser/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.zip
   [ivy:resolve]    ==== maven2: tried
   [ivy:resolve]      http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.zip
   [ivy:resolve]    ==== jboss-maven2: tried
   [ivy:resolve]        http://repository.jboss.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.zip

   [ivy:resolve]        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
   [ivy:resolve]        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
   [ivy:resolve]        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [ivy:resolve]        :: org.mortbay.jetty#jetty;6.1.26!jetty.zip
```

JETTY JAR FILES ARE AVAILABLE

```
  pig-0.13.0 hduser> ls /Users/hduser/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26
   _remote.repositories     jetty-6.1.26.jar.lastUpdated    jetty-6.1.26.jar.sha1       jetty-  6.1.26.pom.lastUpdated
   jetty-6.1.26.jar         jetty-6.1.26.pom        jetty-6.1.26.pom.sha1
```

ENVIRONMENT
OS X version 10.9.4. 
I use HomeBrew as my package installer.
pig-0.13.0 hduser> ls /usr/local/Cellar
ant     coreutils   mysql       openssl

ACTIONS
*  I did this exercise just last week and it worked first time. 
*  I have run builds on pig-0.13.0.src.tar.gz and pig-0.12.1.tar.gz with the same error.
*  I have Google hunted the error message for jetty. * My first question is why is the build looking for a zip file when the jar file is already there?

HYPOTHESIS
I make changes in my development environment. This may be a result of an environmental change. If so recommendations on tool installs or libraries are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected. There is no root cause. I completely rebuild my dev environment. I suspect my upgrade to either Eclipse Luna or upgrade of Xcode causes the error, but have no proof. Ant now does build the h2 file as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a while back, I believe I tracked the problem down to the Ant build script wanting a zip file. When I used HomeBrew to install it uncompressed the zip file. I believe I tested this theory by installing directly from the tar file and found it ran correctly. But I also had made a number of modifications and additions to my dev environment. I rolled back the various updates and then this Ant build ran even after using HomeBrew to install Pig. Not a very good root cause, but I have not experience the problem again. 
Hope this helps.
wkd

Answer (score 0):

`jetty-6.1.26.zip` can't be downloaded from the sites ivy tried. You need to manually download `jetty-6.1.26.zip`.

Go to [here](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/jetty-6.1.26.zip.25894195-0.html) to download `jetty-6.1.26.zip`. Then put the zip file to `/YOUR_HOME_DIR/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/`. Finally execute `ant` to build.